# How to detect when a TextField becomes active in SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, swiftui

```
.onTapGesture {
   // do something
}
```

Doesn't work because TextFields can be tapped without beginning editing mode.

Comment: Check out FocusState if you’re using iOS15+

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The answer is to initialize TextField with the onEditingChanged parameter.

We can then execute a closure conditionally depending upon whether the text field was edited or changes were committed:

```
TextField("", text: $email, onEditingChanged: { changed in
  if changed {
    // User began editing the text field
  }
  else {
    // User tapped the return key
  }
})
```

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried with **onEditingChanged**

```
    .onEditingChanged {
         //do something cool
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

You Should try with it ,

```
onEditingChanged: { (isBegin) in
                if isBegin {
                    print("Begins editing")
                } else {
                    print("Finishes editing")
                }
            },
```